# How to configure the printer to print images using the printer Bluetooth device Android

Tags: printing, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, printer-control-language

I want print bill to printer Bluetooth device, It's look 
[image]

But It's see
[image]

Here Code:

```
private void print_image(String file) throws IOException {

    File fl = new File(file);
    OutputStream os = mBluetoothSocket
            .getOutputStream();
    if (fl.exists()) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
        convertBitmap(bmp);
        os.write(PrinterCommands.SET_LINE_SPACING_24);

        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < bmp.getHeight()) {
            os.write(PrinterCommands.SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE);
            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.getWidth(); ++x) {

                for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {

                    byte slice = 0;
                    for (int b = 0; b < 8; ++b) {
                        int y = (((offset / 8) + k) * 8) + b;
                        int i = (y * bmp.getWidth()) + x;
                        boolean v = false;
                        if (i < dots.length()) {
                            v = dots.get(i);
                        }
                        slice |= (byte) ((v ? 1 : 0) << (7 - b));
                    }
                    os.write(slice);
                }
            }
            offset += 24;


            os.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            os.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);          
            os.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            os.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            os.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
            os.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
        }
        os.write(PrinterCommands.SET_LINE_SPACING_30);


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "file doesn't exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}

AND PrinterCommands.class


  public static final byte[] INIT = {27, 64}; public static byte[]
  FEED_LINE = {10};

  public static byte[] SELECT_FONT_A = {27, 33, 0};

  public static byte[] SET_BAR_CODE_HEIGHT = {29, 104, 100}; public static
  byte[] PRINT_BAR_CODE_1 = {29, 107, 2}; public static byte[]
  SEND_NULL_BYTE = {0x00};

  public static byte[] SELECT_PRINT_SHEET = {0x1B, 0x63, 0x30, 0x02};
  public static byte[] FEED_PAPER_AND_CUT = {0x1D, 0x56, 66, 0x00};

  public static byte[] SELECT_CYRILLIC_CHARACTER_CODE_TABLE = {0x1B, 0x74,
  0x11};


  public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, (byte) 255,
  3}; public static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACING_24 = {0x1B, 0x33, 24}; public
  static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACING_30 = {0x1B, 0x33, 30};
```

Help me config PrinterCommands true

Comment: did you find answer, I have a some problem